# Declaring a variable in a for loop using the index (i)

Tags: java, android, variables, dynamic, loops

I am so close to getting this project to work, but I'm stuck on one thing that is driving me crazy and I can't find anything in my research that is working.

What I need to do is declare a new variable each time the for loop passes through the recordset, but I need to use the index value (i) in the variable name.

The line I need help with is `Bottles o[i] = new Bottles();`

I need to define a new variable each time the for loop passes through again, for example, my variables should end up being o1, o2, o3, etc.  I'm getting a syntax error on the [i] right now and I can't seem to find out how to do this.

Any thoughts on what I'm missing here?

```
private void getBottles() {
        try {
            m_bottles = new ArrayList<Bottles>();
            for (int i = 0; i < bottleNamesMap.size(); i++) {
                Bottles o[i] = new Bottles();
                o[i].setbottleID(bottleIntMap.get("bottleID" + i));
                o[i].setname_abbr(bottleNamesMap.get("name" + i));
                o[i].setorigin(bottleNamesMap.get("origin" + i));
                o[i].setbottlePicture(bottleNamesMap.get("bottlePicture" + i));
                o[i].setprice_reported(bottleNamesMap.get("price" + i));
                o[i].setdistillery(bottleNamesMap.get("distillery" + i));
                o[i].setagg_score(bottleIntMap.get("aggscore" + i));
                m_bottles.add(o[i]);
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                Log.i("ARRAY", "" + m_bottles.size());
            }
          } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("BACKGROUND_PROC", e.getMessage());
          }
          runOnUiThread(returnRes);
      }
```

Comment: Note that you cannot *name* variables during runtime. The only thing you can do it get an element from the list o, using i as an index. The return value is an unnamed reference to a Bottle. Furthermore, I should take a very careful look at what "Bottles" actually represents, and I would certainly advise you to read the Java naming conventions http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367 .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
 Bottles o[i] = new Bottles();
```

should be:

```
  Bottles o = new Bottles();
```

Then drop the `[i]`. The new keyword will create a new object each iteration.

```
            Bottles o = new Bottles();
            o.setbottleID(bottleIntMap.get("bottleID"+i));
            o.setname_abbr(bottleNamesMap.get("name"+i));
            o.setorigin(bottleNamesMap.get("origin"+i));
            o.setbottlePicture(bottleNamesMap.get("bottlePicture"+i));
            o.setprice_reported(bottleNamesMap.get("price"+i));
            o.setdistillery(bottleNamesMap.get("distillery"+i));
            o.setagg_score(bottleIntMap.get("aggscore"+i));
            m_bottles.add(o);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
Bottles o = new Bottles();
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the index in the variable name - that's just for the compiler.  You could just say

Bottles bottles = new Bottles();

then use bottles everywhere you use o[i];

Each time through the loop a new Bottles will be created - despite the fact that the variable name is the same, it is a distinct object, and you can index it later via the ArrayList.